# How can I optimize writing BIG files?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, delta-lake

I have a dataframe with 120 millions of records and when i try to write it, takes 45 minutes.
The DF is partitioned by a field "id_date" which is in this format: yyyymmdd.
This DF is a delta table in databricks.
I try with autooptimize, compact, etc from delta tables properties but i don´t get any advance.
Sorry for my bad english.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks and regards

I am trying to write a df with many records (more than 100 million) and it takes me a long time.
I need to optimize this process.

Comment: Did you try to `.repartition(N)` before writing?

Comment: No, do you think that repartition helps? In that case the number of "N" should be get from df.rdd.getNumPartitions()). Thanks

Comment: Increasing the partitions means increasing the parallelism of processing/saving the data, but you need to take care of the resources limitation so it doesn't become an overhead, so we don't use the `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` since this will have no effect but usually it is the number of cores in the cluster * a factor of 2 or 3, so if you have 10 cores then you can try to set it as 20 or 30

Comment: i have tried this but still takes very long time. Here you can see the spark_ui.  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Zu-bKe_WBr-00k1LGHGLWx6LqY-j3xu/view?usp=sharing
In executor 2 the records are increasing up to, in this case, 16 million (you can see in image that is in 2 m. ). But all in the same executor so it takes a long time. Any suggestions. Thanks again

Comment: Could you try to add the partition column as well `.repartition(N, $"id_date")`?

Comment: Yes, that sparkui image is with this command: display(df_join_tornos.repartition(4, "id_fecha").count())

Comment: Could it be that the write operation is not the problem but spark is spending time processing the transformations? Could you share the execution plan of your dataframe?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html